# custom form list field add disabled options - create optgroups

Tags: custom-field, jform, form, select

I have a working list based on an sql query. Now I would like to add some spacers (not selectable items).

When doing this manually in xml you can add the disabled attr to that item, but how can I do that when filling the list like so:

```
$cities = array(
    array('value' => 1, 'text' => 'New York'),
    array('value' => 2, 'text' => 'Chicago'),
    array('value' => 3, 'text' => 'San Francisco'),
);
```

I have tried to add `'disabled' => 'true'` to the item array and some different versions of `'attribute' => 'disabled'`, but none of them worked so far.

**EDIT:**
What it should look like:

```
<option value="" disabled>---Letters---</option>
<option value="x">X</option>
<option value="y">Y</option>
<option value="z">Z</option>
<option value="" disabled>---Numbers---</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
...
```

In the rendered output, Letters and Numbers should just be a "divider" in the select list that is not selectable - "optgroups" are the right keyword, yes.

Edit 2:
Okay I've got it now, partly, with the information from mickmackusa:

```
public function getOptions() {
    $type = $this->element['context'];
    $component = $this->element['component'] ? $this->element['component'] : 'com_content';
    $context = $component . '.' . $type;

    $jcFields  = FieldsHelper::getFields($context, '*', true); // get custom field names by article id

    $options = array();

    $options[] = JHTML::_('select.optgroup', '---Article---');
    $options[] = JHTML::_( 'select.option', 'nxItemId', '***Item ID***' );

    $options[] = JHTML::_('select.optgroup', '---Customfields---');
    foreach ($jcFields as $jcField){
        $options[] = JHTML::_( 'select.option', $jcField->name, $jcField->title );
    }
    
    return $options;
}
```

The second optgroup header (*---Customfields---*) will not be rendered.

Comment: Do you mean to add `<optgroup>` tags? They aren't selectable.

Comment: Yes "optgroup" would be the terminus - the list should be "like" in my edit - similar to the Joomla fields with "use global" and "from template"

Comment: If your field class curently extends `JFormFieldList`, you should try `JFormFieldGroupedList` instead.

Comment: @Sharky - That sounds interesting - unfortunately i did not found any docs or examples on how to extend JFormFieldGroupedList how to build the options - can you give me a simple example for two groups? (maybe as response so it could be the solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My question could be solved by the comments of mickmackusa and Sharky.
I have finally extended the *JFormFieldGroupedList* as follows:

```
defined('JPATH_PLATFORM') or die;
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('groupedlist');
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php'); //load fields helper

class JFormFieldNxCustomfieldListKey extends JFormFieldGroupedList
{
    protected $type = 'nxCustomfieldListKey';

    public function getGroups() {

        $jcArticleFields  = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', '*', true); // get custom field names by article id
        $jcContactFields  = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_contact.contact', '*', true); // get custom field names by article id

        $groups = [];

        // Add Module Style Field
        $tmp = JText::_('MOD_NX_GROUP_BASIC');
        $groups[$tmp][] = JHtml::_('select.option', '', JText::_('MOD_NX_EXPOSER_DISABLED'));
        $groups[$tmp][] = JHtml::_('select.option', 'nxItemId', 'Item ID');


        // Create one new option object for each available style, grouped by templates
        $groups['Article Fields'] = [];
        $groups['Contact CustomFields'] = [];

        $grp = JText::_('MOD_NX_ARTICLE_FIELDS');
        foreach ($jcArticleFields as $jcField){
            $groups[$grp][] = JHtml::_('select.option', $jcField->name, $jcField->title);
        }

        $grp = JText::_('MOD_NX_CONTACT_FIELDS');
        foreach ($jcContactFields as $jcField){
            $groups[$grp][] = JHtml::_('select.option', $jcField->name, $jcField->title);
        }

        return $groups;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent job resolving your question.   May I ask why `reset()` is called? I don't see that the array pointer was ever advanced, so my feeling is that this line of code does nothing.  Do you know otherwise?  Also, I would not bother declaring the single-use variable `$tmp` -- just push the `JHtml...` value directly into `$groups[$grp][]`.

Comment: Yeah its a bit of a "Frankenstein Monster" - indeed it needs to be improved. Basically its based on the chromestyle.php from joomlatools found in https://github.com/joomlatools/joomlatools-platform/blob/master/lib/libraries/cms/form/field/chromestyle.php

Comment: In that case, let's break the bad cycle of copy-pasta and fix what can be sensibly fixed.

Comment: It never ceases to amaze me how many people don't have a basic understanding of regex.  `[\s\t]` should be `\s` and `[a-z0-9\-\_]` should be `[\w-]`.  Underscores don't have special meaning to regex, so they don't need escaping.   ...but I digress.

Comment: hey i was on the way to do that but had first to implement „my code“ into my module. - what do you mean with the regex @mickmackusa?

Comment: There was some misunderstood/unoptimised regex in the repo file that you linked to -- not associated with your actual code.